# pyspark rdd map is not calling function

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I am trying to do few transformations on my RDD and for that, I am calling a function using map. However, this function is not getting invoked. Someone please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

I can see `test` function getting invoked but not `store_past_info`

```python
def store_past_info(row):
    print "------------------- store_past_info  ------------------------------"

    if row["transactiontype"] == "Return":
        global prv_transaction_number
        prv_transaction_number = row["transnumber"]
        global return_occured
        return_occured = True
        global group_id
        group_id.append(row["transnumber"])

    if row["transactiontype"] == "Purchase":
            if return_occured:
                global group_id
                group_id.append(prv_transaction_number)
            else:
                global group_id
                group_id.append(row["transnumber"])

    print group_id


def test(rdd):
    print "------------------- test  ------------------------------"
    rdd.map(store_past_info).collect()
    print group_id
```

This is how it works in store:

1. if some item is purchased an id is generated.
2. if you want to return few items from your purchase, two entries are been made

   1. Return entry with new id for the return of all the products, with `org_id` as `id` of your purchase order you want to return
   2. New Purchase entry with the same `id` as your last purchase id for things you want to keep

**Input**

```python
Date        Type        Id      org_id
25-03-2018  Purchase    111 
25-03-2018  Purchase    112 
26-03-2018  Return      113     111    
26-03-2018  Purchase    111
```

**Output**
I want to add a new column group_id, which will show the same id for Return and Corresponding Purchase happened after return ( customer don't do this purchase, this is how system keeps entry for every return) **step 2.1**

```python
Date        Type        Id      org_id  group_id
25-03-2018  Purchase    111             111 
25-03-2018  Purchase    112             112
26-03-2018  Return      113     111     113
26-03-2018  Purchase    111             113
```

Comment: I don't think you can use global variables in the manner you are attempting to in pySpark. What is it that you're trying to do? Can you provide some sample input/desired output?

Comment: @pault I have updated the question. However, I don't see function getting invoked as well.

Comment: Can you give some more detail on how you go from the input to the output? I think you're better suited solving this problem using dataframes and Window functions, but I am still not 100% clear on your logic.

Comment: @pault please check if the question is more clear now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IIUC, I believe you can get your output using `DataFrame`s, a `pyspark.sql.Window` function, and `crossJoin()`

First convert your `rdd` to a DataFrame using

```python
df = rdd.toDF()  # you may have to specify the column names
df.show()
#+----------+--------+---+------+
#|      Date|    Type| Id|org_id|
#+----------+--------+---+------+
#|25-03-2018|Purchase|111|  null|
#|25-03-2018|Purchase|112|  null|
#|26-03-2018|  Return|113|   111|
#|26-03-2018|Purchase|111|  null|
#+----------+--------+---+------+
```

Then we will need to add an Index column to keep track of the order of the rows. We can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id). This will guarantee that the values will be increasing (so they can be ordered), but does not mean that they will be sequential.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df = df.withColumn('Index', f.monotonically_increasing_id())
df.show()
#+----------+--------+---+------+-----------+
#|      Date|    Type| Id|org_id|      Index|
#+----------+--------+---+------+-----------+
#|25-03-2018|Purchase|111|  null| 8589934592|
#|25-03-2018|Purchase|112|  null|17179869184|
#|26-03-2018|  Return|113|   111|34359738368|
#|26-03-2018|Purchase|111|  null|42949672960|
#+----------+--------+---+------+-----------+
```

The ordering is important because you want to look for rows that come after a Return.

Next use [`crossJoin`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.crossJoin) to join the `DataFrame` to itself.

Since this returns the Cartesian product, we will filter it to just the rows that meet *either* of the following conditions:

- `l.Index = r.Index` (essentially join a row to itself)
- `(l.Id = r.org_id) AND (l.Index > r.Index)` (an `Id` is equal to a `org_id` from an earlier row- this is where the Index column is helpful)

Then we add a column for `group_id` and set it equal to `r.Id` if the second condition is met. Otherwise we set this column to `None`.

```python
df1 = df.alias('l').crossJoin(df.alias('r'))\
    .where('(l.Index = r.Index) OR ((l.Id = r.org_id) AND (l.Index > r.Index))')\
    .select(
        'l.Index',
        'l.Date',
        'l.Type',
        'l.Id',
        'l.org_id',
        f.when(
            (f.col('l.Id') == f.col('r.org_id')) & (f.col('l.Index') > f.col('r.Index')),
            f.col('r.Id')
        ).otherwise(f.lit(None)).alias('group_id')
    )
df1.show()
#+-----------+----------+--------+---+------+--------+
#|      Index|      Date|    Type| Id|org_id|group_id|
#+-----------+----------+--------+---+------+--------+
#| 8589934592|25-03-2018|Purchase|111|  null|    null|
#|17179869184|25-03-2018|Purchase|112|  null|    null|
#|34359738368|26-03-2018|  Return|113|   111|    null|
#|42949672960|26-03-2018|Purchase|111|  null|     113|
#|42949672960|26-03-2018|Purchase|111|  null|    null|
#+-----------+----------+--------+---+------+--------+
```

We are almost there but as you can see there are two things that still need to be done.

1. We need to eliminate the duplicate row for `Index = 42949672960`
2. We need to fill in the `group_id` for rows where it is `null` using the value from `Id`.

For the first step, we will use a `Window` function to create a temporary column called `rowNum`. This will be the [`pyspark.sql.functions.row_number()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.row_number) for each `Index` ordered by the boolean condition `group_id IS NULL`.

For the Index values where there are multiple rows, the one where the `group_id` has already been set will sort first. Thus we just need to select the rows where the `rowNum` is equal to 1 (`row_number()` starts at 1, not 0).

After this is done, the second step is trivial- just replace the remaining `null` values with the value from `Id`.

```python
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.partitionBy(f.col('Index')).orderBy(f.isnull('group_id'))
df2 = df1.withColumn('rowNum', f.row_number().over(w))\
    .where(f.col('rowNum')==1)\
    .sort('Index')\
    .select(
        'Date',
        'Type',
        'Id',
        'org_id',
        f.when(
            f.isnull('group_id'),
            f.col('Id')
        ).otherwise(f.col('group_id')).alias('group_id')
    )

df2.show()
#+----------+--------+---+------+--------+
#|      Date|    Type| Id|org_id|group_id|
#+----------+--------+---+------+--------+
#|25-03-2018|Purchase|111|  null|     111|
#|25-03-2018|Purchase|112|  null|     112|
#|26-03-2018|  Return|113|   111|     113|
#|26-03-2018|Purchase|111|  null|     113|
#+----------+--------+---+------+--------+
```

Comment: in spark 1.6 `crossJoin` is not available so I used `join(how='cross)